# Running unit tests with a local node in Elastic4S 7.x

Tags: elastic4s

I'm in the process of upgrading my system to Elasticsearch / Elastic4S 7.3, but I've hit a problem with my unit tests. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

Currently (with E4S 6.1.4) I use the ClassLocalNodeProvider to give me a local http client for the tests (which run remotely in Travis for each GitHib pull request)

In E4S 7.x there seems to be no direct replacement for LocalNode (?)

I did try replacing ClassLocalNodeProvider with ClientProvider in the code below, but it looks like I would then need to supply a concrete definition for client: ElasticClient (the ES7 version of my ElasticClientProvider class does expect an ElasticClient rather than an HttpClient).

```
class ElasticsearchRepositorySpec extends WordSpec with SearchMatchers with ClassLocalNodeProvider with HttpElasticSugar {

  val testClient: HttpClient = http

  val elasticClientProvider: ElasticClientProvider = new ElasticClientProvider {
    override def client: HttpClient = testClient
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

LocalNode is no longer supported in E4S, I'm now using a Docker plugin instead to create a vanilla ES node to run the tests. Works locally, not tested yet with Travis or Concourse. The container does take a little while to start then it runs on localhost with a dynamically allocated port number.

```
import org.testcontainers.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchContainer  

val container = new ElasticsearchContainer()
container.setDockerImageName("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.3.0")
container.start()

val host = container.getHttpHostAddress()
val client: ElasticClient = new ElasticClient(JavaClient(ElasticsearchClientUri(s"http://${host}?ssl=false")))
```

Comment: The ElasticClient constructor I used no longer works in E4S, replacement sample code (could be more concise) below  `val containerHost = container.getHttpHostAddress()
  val host =  containerHost.split(":").headOption.getOrElse("localhost")
  val port =  Try(containerHost.split(":").lastOption.getOrElse("9200").toInt).getOrElse(9200)

  val elEndpoint: ElasticNodeEndpoint = new ElasticNodeEndpoint("http",host,port,None)
  val eProps: ElasticProperties = new ElasticProperties(endpoints = Seq(elEndpoint))

  val client: ElasticClient = new ElasticClient(JavaClient(eProps))`